# Is com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms stored with the file?

Tags: metadata

If you look at an image in Finder there is a "where from" field which is the URL that the image is downloaded from. That "where from" field seems to be stored in com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms. Is the com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms attribute stored within the image file or is it floating somewhere else in the file system.

Answer (score 2):

This is an [extended file attribute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes). The data is stored in the attribute data record which is a feature of the file system. The file remains unmodified.